# Macro string concat using python

Tags: python-2.7

I need to create a variable in runtime. How do I do this using python

ex:

```
for l in self.device.output.split("\n"):
    r1 = re.match("(?P<phy>(te|gi)+)", l.strip(), re.IGNORECASE) 
    if r1 is not None:
        s = l.split(' ')
```

Here `s` will be of form : `['GigabitEthernet4/0/1', '', '', 'unassigned', '\r']`

I need to create a variable like this

```
s[0]_myqueue0 
s[0]_myqueue1
```

So that I can assign values to above `myqueues` later in the program

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying todo, there are many ways to create names at runtime.

The easiest option is to use a dictionary and assign keys to functions or pieces of code that you want to run later:

```
code_map = dict()

# later on in your code

code_map[s[0]]['myqueue0'] = 'foo'
```

This will result in:

```
>>> print(code_map['GigabitEthernet4/0/1']['myqueue0'])
foo
```

Comment: For some reason the above isnt working:  I get this error:  File "monitor_qos.py", line 365, in initialize
    code_map['s[0]']['myqueue0'] = 'foo'
KeyError: 's[0]'
bash-3.2$

Comment: Don't add quotes around the key. Have a look at the code.

Comment: I am not sure what I am missing, but it still doesnt work: `for l in self.device.output.split("\n"):
            r1 = re.match("(?P<phy>(te|gi)+)", l.strip(), re.IGNORECASE) 
            if r1 is not None:
                s = l.split(' ')
                self.ifaces.append(s[0])
               self.code_map[s[0]]['myqueue0'] = 'foo' `     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "monitor_qos.py", line 928, in <module>
    if v.initialize():
  File "monitor_qos.py", line 364, in initialize
    self.code_map[s[0]]['myqueue0'] = 'foo'
KeyError: 'GigabitEthernet4/0/1'
bash-3.2$

Comment: just doing `code_map = dict()` and then `code_map[s[0]]['myqueue0'] = 'foo'` won't work, because then `code_map[s[0]]` won't point to anything. Then trying to assign to `code_map[s[0]]['myqueue0']` won't work. Maybe you could get it working if you used a defaultdict(dict)...